# Visual Studio Diad? SafeMode not working either

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was in the middle of debugging with VS210Pro that it crashed with some SVCHost error. After that when I want to open it I get this error:

[image]

The only thing I knew was safemode command, "devenv /SafeMode ", tried that. This didn't help either. So I am about to uninstall VS and reinstall it. A good two hours or so of the day will be gone :) so before starting to uninstall, I thought let's ask a question, maybe there is other ways for recovering VS that I am not aware of...

Comment: Googling..also tried this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2626696  ..after I ran the command listed here Now I got a .NET Framewrok has stopped working error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The problem was caused by some updates from McAfee antivirus!